# How can you programmatically retrieve the comments made on a photo in your iOS photo stream?

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary, alasset

ALAsset contains the metadata for an image, which includes resolution, camera settings and location, but it doesn't appear to include comments from a photo stream.

That makes sense, but I would like to retrieve those comments.

Does anyone know if it is possible and where they might be stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you can access user comments for a specific image format only. The one mentioned is for Exchangeable Image File Format (EXIF).

```
const CFStringRef kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment;
```

Take a look the [CGImageProperties Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageProperties_Reference/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: I think these comments are the ones created at the time of the image or by the camera.  I am looking for the comments that people leave on the image using the Photos app, particularly 'Shared Streams'

Comment: If the above did not solve your issue then I do not think there is a way to do it, at least yet. I read the ALAssetsLibrary Class Reference again and there is no mention of comments anywhere. It looks like you cannot do it. Here is the link to the ALAssetsLibrary Class Reference (take a look at the Constants) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009722-CH1-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: Yes, I am coming to that conclusion as well.  Thanks for taking time to look into it.